# Touch ID slows down the app or crash

Tags: ios, performance, touch-id

I really dont know what happened to my app but since I've added the touchid function, app is slower then before and strange writings appear.
I've added a `UiViewController` before the main controller, so I can check there without show any data to the user until he logged success with touchid.
All right, on my iphone 6s also, but it is very very slow now and it has appeared this on my console after the success of the touchid function:

```
success!!!!
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView bounds]
PID: 8460, TID: 1642991, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   LAMer                               0x000000010c035d96 _T0So16UIViewControllerC5LAMerE14displaySpinnerSo0A0CAF6onView_tFZ + 54
5   LAMer                               0x000000010c060a85 _T05LAMer18AuthViewControllerC13viewDidAppearySbFySbcfU_ + 245
6   LAMer                               0x000000010c060e4e _T05LAMer18AuthViewControllerC13viewDidAppearySbFySbcfU_TA + 62
7   LAMer                               0x000000010c0374d0 _T0So16UIViewControllerC5LAMerE25authenticationWithTouchIDyySbc10completion_tFySb_s5Error_pSgtcfU_ + 336
8   LAMer                               0x000000010c037c2c _T0So16UIViewControllerC5LAMerE25authenticationWithTouchIDyySbc10completion_tFySb_s5Error_pSgtcfU_TA + 108
9   LAMer                               0x000000010c037cb3 _T0Sbs5Error_pSgIxyx_SbSo7NSErrorCSgIyByy_TR + 115
10  LocalAuthentication                 0x000000010f42edf6 __50-[LAContext evaluatePolicy:localizedReason:reply:]_block_invoke_2 + 72
11  LocalAuthentication                 0x000000010f42e2a9 __42-[LAContext evaluatePolicy:options:reply:]_block_invoke_2 + 615
12  LocalAuthentication                 0x000000010f4293df __52-[LAClient evaluatePolicy:options:uiDelegate:reply:]_block_invoke + 224
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001124dc2f7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001124dd33d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001124e2251 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 1458
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001124e9102 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 772
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001124e8da0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001129a81ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001129a7c4d start_wqthread + 13
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView initWithFrame:]
PID: 8460, TID: 1642991, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   LAMer                               0x000000010c03802d _T0So6UIViewCABSC6CGRectV5frame_tcfcTO + 77
5   LAMer                               0x000000010c036064 _T0So6UIViewCABSC6CGRectV5frame_tcfC + 100
6   LAMer                               0x000000010c035db3 _T0So16UIViewControllerC5LAMerE14displaySpinnerSo0A0CAF6onView_tFZ + 83
7   LAMer                               0x000000010c060a85 _T05LAMer18AuthViewControllerC13viewDidAppearySbFySbcfU_ + 245
8   LAMer                               0x000000010c060e4e _T05LAMer18AuthViewControllerC13viewDidAppearySbFySbcfU_TA + 62
9   LAMer                               0x000000010c0374d0 _T0So16UIViewControllerC5LAMerE25authenticationWithTouchIDyySbc10completion_tFySb_s5Error_pSgtcfU_ + 336
10  LAMer                               0x000000010c037c2c _T0So16UIViewControllerC5LAMerE25authenticationWithTouchIDyySbc10completion_tFySb_s5Error_pSgtcfU_TA + 108
11  LAMer                               0x000000010c037cb3 _T0Sbs5Error_pSgIxyx_SbSo7NSErrorCSgIyByy_TR + 115
12  LocalAuthentication                 0x000000010f42edf6 __50-[LAContext evaluatePolicy:localizedReason:reply:]_block_invoke_2 + 72
13  LocalAuthentication                 0x000000010f42e2a9 __42-[LAContext evaluatePolicy:options:reply:]_block_invoke_2 + 615
14  LocalAuthentication                 0x000000010f4293df __52-[LAClient evaluatePolicy:options:uiDelegate:reply:]_block_invoke + 224
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001124dc2f7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001124dd33d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001124e2251 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 1458
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001124e9102 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 772
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001124e8da0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001129a81ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001129a7c4d start_wqthread + 13
```

After this, main controller appear and data of that controller correctly log into console.
Could I ask you what is this code above that appears in my console and if you are already know that touchid make app doing this stuff..

Thank you in advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like a TouchID issue at all. You are performing UI actions on a background thread. You must call all UI on the main thread.

Look at recent changes to your code and see what you've changed.

Slowness and/or unresponsiveness is classic *UI on a background thread* issue.

See [Main Thread Checker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker)

Comment: I think is about the `applicationWillEnterForeground` but I still need this. How to do what you said "You must call all UI on the main thread"?

Comment: @LudovicoLoreti, What does "I've solved the problem cuased by a static spinner" mean?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker

Comment: See http://blog.grio.com/2014/04/understanding-the-ios-main-thread.html

Comment: @DuncanC there was a problem with a outside function called by another controller and never terminated.